# Sikuli not clicking on found image?

Tags: java, sikuli

Here is what I have currently.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FindFailed {
        Debug.setDebugLevel(3);
        Screen s = new Screen();
        click(s.userCapture().getFile());
}

    private static void click(String image) throws FindFailed{

        Screen screen = new Screen();

        Pattern pattern = new Pattern(image).similar((float) 0.7);

        if(screen.find(pattern) != null)
        { 
            screen.mouseMove(pattern); 
            screen.click(pattern); 
        }
    }
```

Basically this is a simple script to click on a selected portion of the screen. However while my mouse moves to the selected portion, the screen.click(pattern) method is not working. (the button I selected has not been clicked). Here is the debug that it outputs.

```
[debug] P(C:\Users\Clinder\AppData\Local\Temp\sikuli-2679855232724202895.png) S: 0.7 has appeared.
[debug] waiting for P(C:\Users\Clinder\AppData\Local\Temp\sikuli-2679855232724202895.png) S: 0.7 to appear
[debug] Screen.capture: java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=1280,height=800]
[debug] RobotDesktop: captureScreen: on 0 using java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=1280,height=800]
[debug] P(C:\Users\Clinder\AppData\Local\Temp\sikuli-2679855232724202895.png) S: 0.7 has appeared.
[debug] waiting for P(C:\Users\Clinder\AppData\Local\Temp\sikuli-2679855232724202895.png) S: 0.7 to appear
[debug] Screen.capture: java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=1280,height=800]
[debug] RobotDesktop: captureScreen: on 0 using java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=1280,height=800]
[debug] P(C:\Users\Clinder\AppData\Local\Temp\sikuli-2679855232724202895.png) S: 0.7 has appeared.
[log] CLICK on L(110,265)@S(0)[0,0 1280x800]
```

Does anyone have ideas for why the click method is not clicking?

Thanks!

**Edit: For some odd reason it works on some programs but not on others. It works on IE, but I'm trying to have it press a log in button on a client and its refusing to press it, just mousing over it.**

Comment: You don't need to add Java in question as you have already tagged the language.

Comment: Looking at your error log I do see that Sikuli has made a click. 
Since it did log `[log] CLICK on L(110,265)@S(0)[0,0 1280x800]`. 
Seems like your app/program is not responding.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your error log I do see that Sikuli has made a click. 
Since it did log `[log] CLICK on L(110,265)@S(0)[0,0 1280x800]`. 
Seems like your app/program is not responding.

It could be that you first need to click on the program or use `App.focus()`
or `App.focusedwindow()` like Barney WaitForIt said. 
 
Becasue somethimes an app/program we see on the screen. But then it is not realy selected. 
 
For example if you open a folder on you windows desktop, and then click next to it. The folder is not the one who is selected.

There are also more App. functions you could use: [Link](http://doc.sikuli.org/javadoc/org/sikuli/script/App.html)